# Setting dynamic value to time-to-live in Spring integration

Tags: java, spring-integration

We have messages coming from the upstream with an expiration timestamp. These messages are to be processed and sent to the downstream with a time-to-live

For various types of messages we receive different expiration timestamp and thus the time-to-live is calculated separately for each message type in a service activator and set to the outbound message header payload as below:

```
MessageBuilder.fromMessage(requestMessage).
setHeader("header1",header1).
setHeader("header2",header2).
setHeader("timeToLive",timeToLive).
setHeader("header3",header3).build();
```

Now, we are using to publish this message as below:

```
<int-jms:outbound-channel-adapter id="publishMessage" channel="publishMessageChannel" header-mapper="headerMapper"
                                     pub-sub-domain="${is.topic}"
                                     destination-name="${outbound.queue}" connection-factory="outputConnectionFactory" order="1" explicit-qos-enabled="true" time-to-live="headers['timeToLive']">
    <int-jms:request-handler-advice-chain>
        <ref bean="retryAdvice" />
    </int-jms:request-handler-advice-chain>
```

Above is throwing the following exception as the time-to-live is set to accept only numbers

> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException: Failed to
>   convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type
>   'long' for property 'timeToLive'; nested exception is
>   java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string:
>   "'headers['timeToLive']'

*We are on SI version 4.3 so cannot use the time-to-live-expression available on later versions*

Need to find a way to get the value of **timeToLive** from enriched header set to **time-to-live** in **int-jms:outbound-channel-adapter**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only the way to fix it for the mentioned version is something similar what we did in the `DynamicJmsTemplate` and `DynamicJmsTemplateProperties`.

So, you need to store a dynamic value in the `ThreadLocal` before sending a message to the `<int-jms:outbound-channel-adapter>`. Extend that `DynamicJmsTemplate` to get access to the mentioned `ThreadLocal` variable in the overridden `getTimeToLive()` method. And clean that `ThreadLocal` value.

Comment: You can't use an expression there; that's why we added the `time-to-live-expression` in 5.1.

It needs a fair amount of support code e.g. updates to the `DynamicJmsTemplate`.

We have no plans to backport it to 4.x so you will need to implement something similar yourself. [This is the PR for the 5.1 implementation](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/pull/2561).

Comment: @ArtemBilan and @GaryRussell Before the `<int-jms:outbound-channel-adapter>` while enriching the message can I set expiration through ? `MessageBuilder.fromMessage(message).setExpirationDate(Instant.now().toEpochMilli() + 20000).build()` or any other custom header?

Comment: No, see JMS spec. The `TTL` can be set only from the provider impl. And what you mention is fully not related to the JMS `TTL`. Please, follow our advises in the answer.

Comment: No; as Artem said, you need to create a customized `JmsTemplate` that gets the TTL from a `ThreadLocal`, and inject the template into the adapter. Some upstream component needs to set the `Threadlocal` and the custom template needs to clear it. Or, of course, upgrade to 5.1.

Comment: You guys rock, this resolved my issue. Thanks for your help